# CSS: Alternating table row color not working

Tags: css, vb.net, colors, html-table, row

I am writing the example CSS table to an html file and the table is working but the alternating row colors is not taking effect.  Is it due to the paragraph

tag perhaps, or the use of table.gridtable?

```
    Dim sw As New StreamWriter(filename)
    sw.WriteLine("<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>")
    sw.WriteLine("<style type=" & """" & "text/css" & """" & ">")
    sw.WriteLine("table.gridtable {")
    sw.WriteLine("  font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;")
    sw.WriteLine("  font-size:12px;")
    sw.WriteLine("  color: #333333;")
    sw.WriteLine("  border-width: 1px;")
    sw.WriteLine("  border-color: #666666;")
    sw.WriteLine("  border-collapse: collapse;")
    sw.WriteLine("}")
    sw.WriteLine("table.gridtable th {")
    sw.WriteLine("  border-width: 1px;")
    sw.WriteLine("  padding: 8px;")
    sw.WriteLine("  border-style: solid;")
    sw.WriteLine("  border-color: #666666;")
    sw.WriteLine("  background-color: #dedede;")
    sw.WriteLine("}")
    sw.WriteLine("table.gridtable tr: nth-child(even) {")
    sw.WriteLine("background-color: #fdf5e6;")
    sw.WriteLine("}")
    sw.WriteLine("table.gridtable td {")
    sw.WriteLine("  border-width: 1px;")
    sw.WriteLine("  padding: 8px;")
    sw.WriteLine("  border-style: solid;")
    sw.WriteLine("  border-color: #666666;")
    sw.WriteLine("  background-color: #ffffff;")
    sw.WriteLine("}")
    sw.WriteLine("</style>")

    sw.Write("<p>")
    sw.WriteLine("<table class=" & """" & "gridtable" & """" & " Align=center>")
    sw.WriteLine("<tr>")
    sw.Write("<th>" & "Output" & "</th>")
    sw.Write("<th>" & "Output" & "</th>")
    sw.Write("<th>" & "Output" & "</th>")
    sw.Write("<th>" & "Output" & "</th>")
    sw.WriteLine("</tr>")
    sw.WriteLine("<tr>")
    sw.WriteLine("<td align=""center""><font color=" & """" & "#000000" & """" & ">Hello</font></td>")
    sw.WriteLine("<td align=""center""><font color=" & """" & "#000000" & """" & ">Hello</font></td>")
    sw.WriteLine("<td align=""center""><font color=" & """" & "#000000" & """" & ">Hello</font></td>")
    sw.WriteLine("<td align=""center""><font color=" & """" & "#000000" & """" & ">Hello</font></td>")
    sw.WriteLine("</tr>")
    sw.WriteLine("<tr>")
    sw.WriteLine("<td align=""center""><font color=" & """" & "#000000" & """" & ">Hello</font></td>")
    sw.WriteLine("<td align=""center""><font color=" & """" & "#000000" & """" & ">Hello</font></td>")
    sw.WriteLine("<td align=""center""><font color=" & """" & "#000000" & """" & ">Hello</font></td>")
    sw.WriteLine("<td align=""center""><font color=" & """" & "#000000" & """" & ">Hello</font></td>")
    sw.WriteLine("</tr>")
    sw.WriteLine("<tr>")
    sw.WriteLine("<td align=""center""><font color=" & """" & "#000000" & """" & ">Hello</font></td>")
    sw.WriteLine("<td align=""center""><font color=" & """" & "#000000" & """" & ">Hello</font></td>")
    sw.WriteLine("<td align=""center""><font color=" & """" & "#000000" & """" & ">Hello</font></td>")
    sw.WriteLine("<td align=""center""><font color=" & """" & "#000000" & """" & ">Hello</font></td>")
    sw.WriteLine("</tr>")
    sw.WriteLine("<tr>")
    sw.WriteLine("<td align=""center""><font color=" & """" & "#000000" & """" & ">Hello</font></td>")
    sw.WriteLine("<td align=""center""><font color=" & """" & "#000000" & """" & ">Hello</font></td>")
    sw.WriteLine("<td align=""center""><font color=" & """" & "#000000" & """" & ">Hello</font></td>")
    sw.WriteLine("<td align=""center""><font color=" & """" & "#000000" & """" & ">Hello</font></td>")
    sw.WriteLine("</tr>")
    sw.WriteLine("</table></p>")
    sw.WriteLine("</body></html>")
    sw.dispose
```

Below is the html code, and removing the space did not resolve the issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<style type="text/css">
table.gridtable {
  font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
  font-size:12px;
  color: #333333;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #666666;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.gridtable th {
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #666666;
  background-color: #dedede;
}
table.gridtable tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #fdf5e6;
}
table.gridtable td {
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #666666;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
</style>
<table class="gridtable" Align=center>
<tr>
<th>Output</th><th>Output</th><th>Output</th><th>Output</th></tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><font color="#000000">Hello</font></td>
<td align="center"><font color="#000000">Hello</font></td>
<td align="center"><font color="#000000">Hello</font></td>
<td align="center"><font color="#000000">Hello</font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><font color="#000000">Hello</font></td>
<td align="center"><font color="#000000">Hello</font></td>
<td align="center"><font color="#000000">Hello</font></td>
<td align="center"><font color="#000000">Hello</font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><font color="#000000">Hello</font></td>
<td align="center"><font color="#000000">Hello</font></td>
<td align="center"><font color="#000000">Hello</font></td>
<td align="center"><font color="#000000">Hello</font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><font color="#000000">Hello</font></td>
<td align="center"><font color="#000000">Hello</font></td>
<td align="center"><font color="#000000">Hello</font></td>
<td align="center"><font color="#000000">Hello</font></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

[image]

Comment: `table.gridtable tr: nth-child(even) {` should be `table.gridtable tr:nth-child(even) {`

Comment: removing the space did not resolve the issue, see the actual html output code now listed in the OP.   Maybe open this in a browser and debug(?) - thx. (is the `color: #333333;` killing the ability to alternate colors?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `background` declaration on `table.gridtable td` is overwriting the stripe `tr` background.

There are a number of ways you can fix that. I moved the `td` background to `tr`, then applied the striping after that.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <style type="text/css">
    table.gridtable {
      font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
      font-size:12px;
      color: #333333;
      border-width: 1px;
      border-color: #666666;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    table.gridtable th {
      border-width: 1px;
      padding: 8px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #666666;
      background-color: #dedede;
    }
      table.gridtable tr {
        background-color: #ffffff;
      }
    table.gridtable tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #fdf5e6;
    }
    table.gridtable td {
      border-width: 1px;
      padding: 8px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #666666;
    }
  </style>
  <table class="gridtable" Align=center>
    <tr>
      <th>Output</th>
      <th>Output</th>
      <th>Output</th>
      <th>Output</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <font color="#000000">Hello</font>
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <font color="#000000">Hello</font>
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <font color="#000000">Hello</font>
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <font color="#000000">Hello</font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <font color="#000000">Hello</font>
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <font color="#000000">Hello</font>
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <font color="#000000">Hello</font>
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <font color="#000000">Hello</font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <font color="#000000">Hello</font>
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <font color="#000000">Hello</font>
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <font color="#000000">Hello</font>
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <font color="#000000">Hello</font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <font color="#000000">Hello</font>
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <font color="#000000">Hello</font>
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <font color="#000000">Hello</font>
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <font color="#000000">Hello</font>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, moved the background color out of the td paragraph into a new tr section, followed by the nth code and it worked -- thanks!

Comment: @wrtsvkrfm it's bad etiquette to ask for additional solutions in the comments. If you have a new problem, you should submit a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the "space" from the pseudo selector.

```
sw.WriteLine("table.gridtable tr: nth-child(even) {")

/** New code **/
sw.WriteLine("table.gridtable tr:nth-child(even) {")
```